# Stick Text view while coordinator layout scroll up side

Tags: android, android-xml, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout, android-transitions

I want to design a screen where there is a circular progress bar. Inside it there is a Text view over there. Now when screen scrolled up(CoolapsingToolbar), circular progress bar should be hide with fade out animation up side in the coordinator layout but the text view inside that circular progress bar should stick there.

When scrolled up following thing should be occured

1. Circular progress bar should be hide with fade out. Space around
   that circular pg should be gone.
2. Middle text view should not be
       hide
3. below Layout Layout1 should be close to textivew

[image]

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
       <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
          <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
               <RelativeLayout>
                 <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

                   <RelativeLayout>
                     <CircularProgressbar>
                     <Middle TextView>
                   </RelativeLayout>
               </CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Any of your login would be welcome. Please give me just logic behind to design this screen. Thank you all.

Actually I want to design this screen [Click to show full screen animation](https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/380805/screenshots/1903238/scroll-animation_dribbble.gif)